# DirectX error with older XP systems

Tags: directx, sound, slimdx

I am a blind programmer, working on an audio game for the blind.
I am using SlimDX, and it has been tested on dozens of systems from XP to Win 8.1.
My code works on most systems just fine, but I am getting the following error at runtime on a handful of older XP systems:

> vupgraderacer.wav SlimDX.DirectSound.DirectSoundException:
>
> DSERR_INVALIDCALL: This call is not valid for the current state of
> this object (-2005401550)
>
> ```
> at SlimDX.Result.Throw[T](Object dataKey, Object dataValue)
> at SlimDX.Result.Record[T](Int32 hr, Boolean failed, Object dataKey, Object dataValue)
> at SlimDX.DirectSound.SecondarySoundBuffer..ctor(DirectSound device, SoundBufferDescription description)
> at RR.Sound..ctor(String fileName)
> ```

The same error is repeated for each sound it is trying to use.
Here is the code I am using to setup the DS device:

> dsDevice = New SlimDX.DirectSound.DirectSound
>
> dsDevice.SetCooperativeLevel(OGw.Handle,
> SlimDX.DirectSound.CooperativeLevel.Normal)

I realize there are other flags that can be set, but this basic setup has worked well thus far, minus the older XP systems.
This is my first post, so hope I am entering it properly, if not, please let me know, it is sometimes difficult to tell where you are or should be with a screenreader on forums.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I edited your question a bit to change the formatting. If you do come across any difficulty using the site, please let us know on [meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What's the result of `SetCooperativeLevel()`? It returns a `HRESULT ` so any value other than `DS_OK` may indicate a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result of SetCooperativeLevel().

According to the documentation of the DirectSound8 version, these are the possible return values:

- DS_OK DSERR_ALLOCATED
- DSERR_INVALIDPARAM
- DSERR_UNINITIALIZED
- DSERR_UNSUPPORTED

Find out which one you get first. Maybe you just forgot to initialize the sound device?

Also, in the remarks section it says: "Do not call this method if any buffers are locked."

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.idirectsound8.idirectsound8.setcooperativelevel%28v=vs.85%29.aspx